# How can I find the number of cliques given a graph G in python?

Tags: python, graph, social-networking, networkx, clique

I need to have two pieces of information, given a graph G:

1. The number of cliques in G.
2. The relative size of those cliques.

For example: there are 3 cliques of size 3, 10 cliques of size 4, 7 cliques of size 5 etc.

I am using Python and I know there are many functions defined in the library networkx. Can anyone help me get these results?

Comment: A minimal amount of searching led me to https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques.html You're welcome

Comment: I think you will find it difficult to find a network with 10 cliques of size 4 and only 3 of size 3.

Comment: That was only an example. I know it is impossible to have that result, I have only written an example of the kind of result i want to read.